# Convergence of average implies convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose that I have a function $N(\varepsilon)$ such that $N(\varepsilon)\to \infty$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$ (take $N(\varepsilon)=[1/\varepsilon]$ for simplicity). Provided that $0\leq a_n\leq 1$ and
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{N(\varepsilon)}\sum_{n=0}^{N(\varepsilon)-1}a_n$$
converges, what can be said about
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{N(\varepsilon)}\sum_{n=N(\varepsilon)}^\infty a_n.$$
I thought the answer to this would be relatively straightforward. Namely, I would expect this second limit to evaluate to zero since the tail end of the first series gets small. I get confused with taking limits inside the bounds of the summation however and am unsure when this is/isn't valid.

Comment: I assume that $N(\epsilon)$ is a positive integer and that $a_n$ is a real number. Are there any restrictions on $a_n$? I ask because we can make $\sum_{n=N(\epsilon)}^\infty a_n$ diverge by taking $a_n$ to be the sequence $+1, -1, +1, +1, -1, -1, \ldots$ and $N(\epsilon)$ to be $2 \cdot (1+2+\cdots+\lfloor 1/\epsilon \rfloor)$, despite that $\sum_{n=0}^{N(\epsilon)-1} a_n$ always evaluates to $0$.

Comment: @user757173 Let's suppose that $N(\varepsilon)= [1/\varepsilon]$ with $0\leq a_n \leq 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: What is $\sum_{n=N(\varepsilon)}^\infty a_n$? You are not assuming that $a_n\geq 0$ so this sum may not exist.

Comment: See the above comment @geetha290krm

Comment: Take $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Your first quantity converges to $0$. Your second one is divergent (tails of the divergent harmonic series are divergent). Or you can just take $a_n=1$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

We can see that:
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{N(\varepsilon)}\sum_{n=0}^{N(\varepsilon)-1}a_n=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=0}^{N(\varepsilon)-1}\frac{a_n}{N(\varepsilon)}$$

From the fact $N(\varepsilon)\to\infty$ when $\varepsilon\to0$ and from the fact that this series is convergent we can say that $\displaystyle\frac{a_n}{N(\varepsilon)}\to0$, when $N(\varepsilon)\to\infty$ and $n\to\infty$.

Now if we look at the series $\displaystyle\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{N(\varepsilon)}\sum_{n=N(\varepsilon)}^\infty a_n=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=N(\varepsilon)}^\infty \frac{a_n}{N(\varepsilon)}$. Here, too, we can see that $N(\varepsilon)\to\infty$ which implies $n\to \infty$. So we get the sum in which all elements $\displaystyle\frac{a_n}{N(\varepsilon)}\to0$, because $N(\varepsilon)\to\infty$ and $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum a_n$ is divergent then $\sum_{n=N(\varepsilon)}^{\infty}a_n=\infty$ and then the second limit is $\infty$. This is the case when $\displaystyle\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{N(\varepsilon)}\sum_{n=0}^{N(\varepsilon)-1}a_n=l$ with $l>0$ because then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{N(\varepsilon)-1}a_n\sim l N(\varepsilon)$ when $\varepsilon$ gets close to zero.
So to get a finite $l^*=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{N(\varepsilon)}\sum_{N(\varepsilon)}^{\infty}a_n$ it is necessary that $\sum a_n$ be convergent, and letting then $S$ its sum, one has $0\leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}a_k\leq S$ hence $l^*=0$.

Comment: It's not neccessary that $\sum{a_n}$ converges, for example take $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $N(\varepsilon)=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$.